# ajax response is showing javascript and not hidding it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building a comment system in which there is features like: delete main post, delete comment, delete reply, edit main post, edit comment, edit reply, Read more/Read less for post that is >250 character. So i am now at the stage of making the edit for reply post to a comment, everything else is working perfectly except this one, when i click i need to see reply post with Read More/Read Less feature, so to make this happen after ajax response i needed to paste the javascript codes for this feature in the php script which edit the reply, so when i make `.html(data)` i see the javascript codes inside the span which i want the response to be shown ! please help ! i made the same script for comment and same way placing javascript code in the php page that edited the comment but i do not see the javascript lines ! below are pictures that shows what is happening and my script next :

```
    // THIS TAKES CARE OF THE EDIT FEATURE OF THE REPLY ON BOARD_COMMENT PAGE 
$(document).on("click", ".board_reply_edit_button", function() {
    // this will select the form in which is contained the edit button
    var editBoardButtonAttribute = $(this).attr("id");
    var editBoardButtonIdArray = editBoardButtonAttribute.split("-");
    var editBoardButtonId = editBoardButtonIdArray[0];

    $("#"+editBoardButtonId+"-formBoardReplyEdit").toggle();
    $("#"+editBoardButtonId+"-spanBoardReplyEdit").toggle();

    // if the cancel button is clicked, this happens
    $(document).on("click", ".board_cancel_button", function() {
        // this will select the form in which is contained the edit button
        var cancelBoardAttribute = $(this).attr("id");
        var cancelBoardButtonIdArray = cancelBoardAttribute.split("-");
        var cancelBoardButtonId = cancelBoardButtonIdArray[0];

        $("#"+cancelBoardButtonId+"-formBoardReplyEdit").hide();
        $("#"+cancelBoardButtonId+"-spanBoardReplyEdit").show();

    });

    // if the edit button is clicked we send this ajax call
    $(document).on("click", ".board_edit_save_button", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // this will select the form in which is contained the edit button
        var saveBoardAttribute = $(this).attr("id");
        var saveBoardButtonIdArray = saveBoardAttribute.split("-");
        var saveBoardButtonId = saveBoardButtonIdArray[0];

        var editBoardTextareaVal = $("#"+saveBoardButtonId+"-textareaBoardReplyEdit").val();

        url = "widgets/edit_board_comment_reply.php";

        if (editBoardTextareaVal === "") {
            CustomSending("This post can't be left blank")
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#sending_box").fadeOut("Slow");
                $("#dialogoverlay").fadeOut("Slow");
            }, 2000);
            // this makes the scroll feature comes back
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
            }, 2001);
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                url: url, 
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    reply_id: saveBoardButtonId,
                    board_reply_textarea: editBoardTextareaVal
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    CustomSending("Sending...");
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#sending_box").fadeOut("Slow");
                    $("#dialogoverlay").fadeOut("Slow");
                    // this makes the scroll feature comes back

                    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");

                    $("#"+saveBoardButtonId+"-spanBoardReplyEdit").html(data); //// THIS IS THE KEY LINE
                    $("#"+saveBoardButtonId+"-formBoardReplyEdit").hide();
                    $("#"+saveBoardButtonId+"-spanBoardReplyEdit").show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

[image: This is the image, key line is in the codes at the end]

this is the edit_board_comment_reply.php file :

```
  <?php 
require_once '../includes/session.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
require_once '../includes/validation_functions.php';


if(isset($_POST['reply_id'], $_POST['board_reply_textarea'])) {
    $reply_id = (int)$_POST['reply_id'];
    $board_reply_textarea = mysql_prep($_POST['board_reply_textarea']);

    // INSERT into table
    $query  = "UPDATE board_comment_reply_table ";
    $query .= "SET reply = '$board_reply_textarea' ";
    $query .= "WHERE reply_id = $reply_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // now we select the updated board post
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM board_comment_reply_table ";
    $query2 .= "WHERE reply_id = $reply_id ";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
    confirm_query($result2);
    $result_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);


}
echo nl2br($result_array['reply']);

?>

<script>
// This takes care of the board comment Continue Reading feature ---------------------------------------------------------
$(".reply_content_span").each(function(){
    var boardReplyPostThis = $(this);
    var boardPostText = $(this).text();
    var boardPostLength = boardPostText.length;
    var boardIdAttribute1 = $(this).attr("id");
    var boardIdAttributeArray1 = boardIdAttribute1.split("-");
    var boardPostId = boardIdAttributeArray1[0];
    var boardPostUserId = boardIdAttributeArray1[1];

    if(boardPostLength > 250) {
        var boardPostTextCut = boardPostText.substr(0, 250);
        boardReplyPostThis.text(boardPostTextCut+"...");
        boardReplyPostThis.append('<a class="board_read_more_link board_reply_read_more" id="'+boardPostId+'-readMoreComment">Read More</a>');
    } else {
        boardReplyPostThis.text(boardPostText);
    }


    $("body").on("click", ".board_reply_read_more", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        boardReplyPostThis.text(boardPostText);
        boardReplyPostThis.append('<a class="board_read_more_link board_reply_read_less">Read Less</a>');
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".board_reply_read_less", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        boardReplyPostThis.text(boardPostTextCut+"...");
        boardReplyPostThis.append('<a class="board_read_more_link board_reply_read_more">Read More</a>');
    });

});

</script>
```

This is the html code :

```
<span class="comment_content_span" id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-spanBoardCommentEdit"><?php echo nl2br($board_comment_text);?></span>
                    <form action="" method="post" class="board_comment_edit_form" id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-formBoardCommentEdit">
                        <textarea rows="2" name="board_comment_edit_textarea" class="board_comment_edit_textarea" id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-textareaBoardEdit"><?php echo $board_comment_text;?></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="board_edit_save_button" id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-saveBoardCommentEdit"/>
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="board_cancel_button" id="<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>-cancelBoardCommentEdit"/>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of edit_board_comment_reply.php script? Maybe there's some kind of escaping

Comment: thanks Philipp for your reply, I added the content of the php page

Comment: Did you wrap the first javascript code fragment in `<script> ... </script>` tags ??

Comment: the first javascript code are in a js file but the second in php file
i made the same thing in the php page of comment edit and it worked well

Comment: You should give the corresponding file name, as title, to each code snippet in your question.

Comment: Well show us the HTML that adds that script to the page. Thats probably where your issue si

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the html code

Comment: How can I eliminate the option of adding the javascript in the php ajax script and keep it in the .js file ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution found !**

instead of the javascript between the script tags, I added this line in the edit_board_comment_reply.php

```
<script src="js/board.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just tested your code (in a very simplified form) and it worked - with `<script>...</script>` and with `<script src="js/board.js"></script>` too. So the problem doesn't reside in how you define the script (betw. tags, or as a referenced js file).

Comment: it should work ! but i don't know why it is not with the script tag, when i add the single line script tag it works well

Comment: Maybe it had to do with the printing `echo nl2br($result_array['reply']);`. See what happens if you just comment that line. Or if you print a simple "abcdef" text.

Comment: this one is to keep the change saved after ajax call

Comment: I thought, if something is weird in the text returned by the `echo nl2br(...)`, then it could affect the proper output of the script tags content.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the appended javascript exitsts in "data" which is send back from your php script. First of all you should try to define the "dataType" property of your ajax-post because the output is preprocessed by jquery depending on that property.

After that you can try to grab just the content-division from your resonse-html and append that instead of the whole result.

For example like this $(body).append($(data).find('#contentID')).

Comment: what do you mean append ? what i am doing right now is taking the text value + the javascript code and place it in a span tag

Comment: If the javascript shows up in your inserted html it's not rendered as javascript. That explains why it works when you add a script tag arround it.
It should be mentioned that this is very bad praxis because every time you load a comment there will be javascript transfered which is already in that page. 

You should consider to rewrite it with an "on" handler.

Comment: AND you should specify the [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) in your ajax-post because it is processed by jquery. If you define it as html instead of text you probably get different results.

Comment: you mean i should not include javascript in my php script used in ajax call ?

Comment: Yeah exactly - the response from the server should only consist of html.
Its better to define a jquery function that will be executed for each "comment-content" regardles if they already exist when the page is loaded.

You can achive this by defining a "on"-function on an element above the dynamic content. "body" for example in most cases exists when the page is loaded.

So instead of telling jquery to call that function directly on a specific element-set you attach it to the body (or any other static element).

Comment: Or wrap the logic which should be executed for each comment-content in a function which is called on succes of the loading off your dynamic content.